# Bitnami HTTPS Configuration Tool - Warning: Please enter valid domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, bitnami

I am trying to use the [Bitnami HTTPS Configuration Tool](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/) to generate an SSL certificate for a LimeSurvey website.

I launch the tool with the following on the Bitnami Stack for Limesurvey (4.4.13-0; hosted on AWS):

`sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool`

This gives the following prompt:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to the Bitnami HTTPS Configuration tool.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domains

Please provide a valid space-separated list of domains for which you wish to 
configure your web server.

Domain list []:
```

For which I enter the URL of the survey:

`http://3.249.162.XXX/index.php/229784?lang=en`

This returns:

```
Warning: Please enter valid domains
Press [Enter] to continue:
```

After pressing `[Enter]` I can see that the URL has been added to the list:

```
Please provide a valid space-separated list of domains for which you wish to 
configure your web server.

Domain list [http://3.249.162.XXX/index.php/229784?lang=en]:
```

However, I am not asked to continue with the process, which indicates (to me at least!) that something has gone wrong. I haven't been able to find an answer to this on any of the Bitnami documentation pages, so, any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: `http://3.249.162.XXX/index.php/229784?lang=en` is not a domain, but a url. A domain is something like `stackoverflow.com` or `www.example.com`

Comment: Bitnami developer here, this is correct, could you add it as the answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Hey both, thank you for your help. Sorry about my mistake! Should I vote to close this question?

Comment: Or I would be happy to accept this as an answer (perhaps others have made this mistake as well) - just let me know what you prefer / think is appropriate.